# Combining boxplots in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset with two columns Q and S. The following shows a sample of it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,40], [2, 51], [3, 59], [4, 10], 
[5, 30], [7, 20], [9, 21], [13, 30], [15, 70], [2, 81], [3, 85], 
[4, 67], [9, 120], [2, 481], [12, 51], [16, 120], [8, 9], [14, 15], 
[11, 7], [12, 110], [6, 4], [9, 220], [1, 40], [2, 15], [14, 82], [7, 50]]),columns=['Q', 'S'])
```

Based on values in column "S" I have defined three groups:

```
Group_1A = df[(df['S'] >= 0) & (df['S'] <= 3)]
Group_2A = df[(df['S'] >= 4) & (df['S'] <= 8)]
Group_3A = df[(df['S'] >= 9) & (df['S'] <= 16)]
```

In addition I have also defined three groups for column "Q":

```
Group_1B = df[(df['Q'] >= 0) & (df['Q'] <= 10)]
Group_2B = df[(df['Q'] >= 11) & (df['Q'] <= 50)]
Group_3B = df[(df['Q'] >= 51) & (df['Q'] <= 481)]
```

I need to figure out the distribution of S for each group and I need to draw a plot that includes all 9 boxplots.

The final plot should be sth like the following image:
[image]

I can plot each individual boxplot, however I have no idea how can I show all of them in one plot.
For example I can plot the boxplot of Group_1A & Group_1B using the following code:

```
df_B1 = df[df['Q']<=10.0]
df_A1_B1 = df_B1[(df_B1['S'] >= 0) & (df_B1['S'] <= 3)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.boxplot(x="S",y="Q", data=df_A1_B1,ax=ax)#,order=order)
```

However, this only gives me 1 out of 9 boxplots that I need.

I am wondering if anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that I need to use matplolib.subplots.